# local variable 'build_data' referenced before assignment

Tags: testflight

When I try to upload an APK file using testflight upload api, I get this response back.

"400 Bad Request.

local variable 'build_data' referenced before assignment"

I don't understand what this is?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT 08/11/2013 10:03** :
It seems like we also get another kind of error sometimes. Which says "Redis is loading data into memory"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TestFlight was experiencing intermittent service outages affecting build uploads. Please try uploading again.

If you have any questions, I recommend contacting TestFlight support directly at:
http://help.testflightapp.com

Comment: Amazed at the quick response time by the TestFlight team!  Considering this answer was just under an hour of the original question being asked, and just 5 hours before I myself saw this!

Comment: Nooo! Why did I procrastinate getting this build to the client until today?

Answer (score 2):

Me also have faced the same problem but after 1 hour I have again tried to upload the build  . I have succeeded in Uploading the build .

Answer (score 1):

I accomplish to upload by using the desktop app.